# What are the alternatives to Smoothie, Merlin and Glidecam for point and shoot cameras?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I would like recommendations for camera stabilizer systems for compact cameras.  That is, those with a gimbal and weights for cameras way below a kilo.

Unfortunately it is illogical that the camera stabilizer costs 3 times more than the camera itself.

Stores are selling me grips instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this is for still photography. Are you shooting video?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can build one yourself. There are many DIY tutorials around, but [I made myself one of those](http://littlegreatideas.com/stabilizer/diy/).

You can scale it down if it's too big or heavy for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Some tradtional camera stabilizers are tend to be expensive since they are serving for professional filming like hollywood-grade movies. But in recent years, some camera stabilization systems like handheld gimbals make revolutionary changes to the cinematography with lower costs and light weights. Picking a camera gimbal stabilizer for your compact cameras depends on what typical camera you are using. Handheld gimbals are designed for different camera sizes they can hold. Here is a **[3-axis handheld gimbal](http://www.gudsen.com)** for lightweight cameras including mirrorless and dslrs.

Comment: Do you have an association with this company? If so, this needs to be declared.